# Values in an array change due to unknown causes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on a genetic algorithm on neural networks together with some friends for a school project, but we've run into a problem. What we're trying to do is the following: (note that some of this is subject to change and only set up this way for testing purposes)

We have 10 neural networks per generation. The first of these is the baseNetwork, the rest are slight variations on the baseNetwork. At the end of the generation, the best performing network is selected as the new baseNetwork for the following generation.
We store neural networks as arrays, for example nn[1] is the first neural network and in itself it is an array.
The problem is that somehow, the baseNetwork is altered after each network rather than at the end of each generation.
Here is the genetic algorithm with some notes to make it a bit easier to follow:

```
function genAlg() {

if (networkNumber < nnPerGen) {
    nn[networkNumber][0][1] = lastfitness; // stores fitness
    nn[networkNumber][0][2] = deathwall; // stores fitness
    networkNumber++; // select new network
    nn[networkNumber] = baseNetwork; // is supposed to replace the currently selected network with the baseNetwork of the generation
    for (i=1; i<=evolveAmt; i++) {
        evolveGate = (Math.floor(gatesAmt * Math.random()) + 1);
        evolve();
    } // make new variation of currently selected network
} else {
    generation++; // start new generation

    for (i=1;i<=nnPerGen;i++) {
        if (nn[i][0][1] > baseNetwork[0][1]) {
            baseNetwork = nn[i];
        } else if (nn[i][0][1] = baseNetwork[0][1]) {
            if (nn[i][0][2] < baseNetwork[0][2]) {
                baseNetwork = nn[i];
            }
        }
    } //Testing fitness, replace baseNetwork if another network is better

    networkNumber = 1; // start working with the first network again
}
}
```

After very thorough testing we have concluded that the problem lies in this line:

nn[networkNumber] = baseNetwork;

We don't know why, but somehow this very line changes the value of baseNetwork itself. Keep in mind that baseNetwork itself is an array.

Comment: `but somehow this very line changes the value of baseNetwork itself.` - no, it doesn't.

Comment: For something this complex, you really need to provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem

Comment: Kind of hard to follow. 
Try `nn[networkNumber] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(baseNetwork));` 
and see if it makes any difference. Perhaps it's some weird pointers to the array or such. Doing this will "copy" the array.

Comment: Dealing with global variables make it hard to understand without the full code :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
nn[networkNumber] = Array.from(baseNetwork);
```

Probably you are giving it the same object reference, so by changing one of them through the evolve fnction you change both. Using `Array.from(baseArray)` you create a new array that is identical to baseArray, but it's a different object